# Brother scanner and OpenSSH / SFTP

Tags: ssh, openssh, brother-printer

I bought a Brother ADS-2700W scanner with SFTP support. Unfortunately, the SFTP connection doesn't work. I use OpenSSH on ArchLinux for the SFTP folder. If I try the SSH Connection from localhost, everything works well, also the publickey authentification. I already added the legacy key algorithms to support the scanner, but still the authentification fails. I tried both, password and publickey authentification, the log messages are exactly the same.

In the following, you can find the SSHD setup, the scanner setup and the log output on SSH. Brother doesn't provide any further error messages or logs.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

## sshd config

```
[root@Thinkpad .ssh]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config 

#Legacy changes
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

Match group sshusers
# ChrootDirectory /home/scan_folder/ # Deactivated for testing SSH connection
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTcpForwarding no
 PasswordAuthentication yes
# ForceCommand internal-sftp # Deactivated for testing SSH connection
```

```
[root@Thinkpad ssh]# cat /etc/passwd |grep scanuser & cat /etc/group |grep sshusers
scanuser:x:1002:1002::/home/scan_folder:/bin/bash
sshusers:x:1002:
```

```
[root@Thinkpad .ssh]# ls -al /home/scan_folder/.ssh/
insgesamt 24
drwx------  2 scanuser sshusers 4096 19. Mai 21:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root     4096 18. Mai 22:48 ..
-rw-------  1 scanuser sshusers 1370 23. Mai 14:46 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 scanuser sshusers 3381 23. Mai 14:38 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 scanuser sshusers  743 23. Mai 14:38 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 scanuser sshusers  659 18. Mai 22:54 known_hosts
```

```
[root@Thinkpad .ssh]# cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N<... rsa key ...> root@<... brother hostname ...>

[root@Thinkpad .ssh]# cat id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N<... rsa key ...> scanuser@Thinkpad
```

## Brother ADS-2700W SFTP config

[ADS2700 SFTP config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfrWR.png)

## Connection log on SSHD

```
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[12572]: debug1: Forked child 13205.
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: Connection from 192.168.1.195 port 48226 on 192.168.1.190 port 22 rdomain ""
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh2_1.4.3
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: compat_banner: no match: libssh2_1.4.3
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 65534/65534 [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: Connection closed by 192.168.1.195 port 48226 [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: do_cleanup
Mai 23 15:04:02 Thinkpad sshd[13205]: debug1: Killing privsep child 13206
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scanner is unable to authenticate the server, not the other way around. From the logs you can see that it doesn't reach the user authentication step.

You've configured this in the scanner:

> Server Public Key: `scanuser.pub`

But that's not the server's public key. The file name sounds very much like it's the *user's* public key, which has nothing to do with server authentication.

The server's public key should be taken from `/etc/ssh/ssh_rsa_host_key.pub`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the issue!